# Why passing a string in a variable as an argument doesn't seem to work while passing the string like '678382234' does

Tags: php, string, api

What I am doing is to pass `$report_request_id` as an argument to a function that should set report request ID, at line `$request->setReportRequestIdList($idList-withId($report_request_id))`. Passing report_request_id in a variable does not seem to work while passing it like `$request->setReportRequestIdList($idList->withId('74838947532'))` does.

```
        if (!empty($report_request_id)) {
            $idList = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList();
            $request->setReportRequestIdList($idList->withId($report_request_id));
        }
```

`$idList->withId()` definition is as follows.

```
/**
 * Sets single or multiple values of Id list via variable number of arguments. 
 * For example, to set the list with two elements, simply pass two values as arguments to this function
 * <code>withId($id1, $id2)</code>
 * 
 * @param string  $stringArgs one or more Id
 * @return MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList  instance
 */


public function withId($stringArgs)
{
    foreach (func_get_args() as $id) {
        $this->fields['Id']['FieldValue'][] = $id;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which shows where you are setting `$report_request_id`? It's likely simply that the variable doesn't contain the value you think it does or somewhere the value was overwritten.

Comment: @alstonp, I later realized there is nothing wrong in the code because the Amazon MWS API doesn't return an Report ID as soon as a request for report is submitted. Thanks for looking into my post.